# Could "there are" be removed in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

It is possible that there are more younger, inexperienced, or more elderly, unsafe drivers in Forestville than (there are) in Elmsford.

Hi, could the (there are) be removed?

Comment: Sure. It's even better if you do that.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to EL&U. We would normally expect a bit more in a question - in particular, why you think "there are" *can't* be removed - and what research you've done before asking here. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

We could argue that the sentence has already had similar parts removed: '...that there are more younger... or [that there are] more elderly...'.

As long as the sentence has a strong enough structure that the the reader can predict, removing such parts is relatively safe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. It is [one form of comparative ellipsis that can happen in *than*-clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative#Independent_ellipsis_mechanisms_in_than-clauses).The first example in the link.

It is not an obligatory rule like [comparative deletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative#Comparative_deletion) or [comparative subdeletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative#Comparative_subdeletion), but an optional one.

This one is called [gapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping).

Since Wikipedia is not a primary source, you can use instead [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4178354.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) in the *Linguistic Inquiry* journal, pubished by MIT press. Case (3) in the article, in which a second instance of the verb is optionally omitted to avoid repetition.